# C# Cross-thread call to update progress bar

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I have a winform that reads in a csv file on a second thread an writes the file data to a console. The main form has a progress bar. I wish to update the progress bar on the main form based on the lines of data read in the second thread. In my second thread function I use:

```
pBar.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
    this.pBar.Value = (int) (((double) nRows) / ((double) fileLines));
});
```

Needless to say this does not seem to work. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

As an aside, should I use pBar.Show() and pBar.Hide() or set pBar.Visible in the second thread to show/hide the progress bar?

Thank you.

Comment: Erm, how do you know the number of lines in the file?  That's usually a chicken-and-egg problem.

Comment: I use: int fileLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fd.FileName).Length;

Comment: So you read the entire contents of the file and then throw them away before re-reading them?!

Comment: I was only doing this for progress bar purposes. I actually read the file and store the info and in the process get the number of lines. I am not sure how to do it elegantly without throwing the info away and rereading it.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably just missing the multiplication by 100 to convert to percent:

```
this.pBar.Value = 100*nRows/fileLines;
```

Assuming `nRows` takes values between `0` and `fileLines` then your code will always set the progress bar value to `0` or `1`.

---

> Should I use `pBar.Show()` and `pBar.Hide()` or set `pBar.Visible` in the second thread to show/hide the progress bar?

Whatever you do in the second thread you should not call methods of a GUI control. Use `BeginInvoke` or `Invoke` to marshal onto the GUI thread.

Comment: I caught and fixed the 100 multiplier and it makes no difference. Regarding the second point, I am not sure I understand what you are saying.

Comment: Well, I can't see anything wrong beyond that. You haven't said how your program fails yet. How about some more details.

Comment: Also, could you try with the built in progress bar. Perhaps your custom painted one is broken.

Comment: The custom bar works fine. The app works, just no progress is shown on the bar.